# Read json data from Powershell script in c# console application

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, botframework, bots

I am trying to read PowerShell script to create a bot service in Azure. I am able to achieve that in windows PowerShell but the same script when i am trying to read from Console app it does not return anything. My purpose is to run this script as a webjob. Below is my c# code

```
  using (Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                myRunSpace.Open();
                using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    // Create a pipeline with the Get-Command command.
                    powershell.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
                    powershell.AddScript(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MyFile.ps1");
                    // add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings
                    // remove this line to get the actual objects
                    powershell.AddCommand("Out-String");
                    // execute the script
                    var results = powershell.Invoke();
                    powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
                    powershell.Commands.Clear();
                    // convert the script result into a single string
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

Here is my script:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount;
$Name="Hello";
$Password="xxxx";
$desc=az ad app create --display-name $Name --password $Password --available-to-other-tenants;
return $desc;
```

This script returns Json in variable "$desc" in windows powershell, but not in console app. Can anyone help me here if am missing anything.

Comment: Can you tell us what you do get as a result from the script when executed within the console?

Comment: @TroyPalacino with the very first command "Connect-AzureRmAccount" i am able to login into Azure. It identifies my tenant, subscription details also i can see this information in Console. After that its blank.

Comment: This might stating the obvious but - although it's a "PowerShell" script, you're invoking the Azure CLI - is the CLI installed wherever this script is running?

Comment: Also, just out of interest, why are you going to all the trouble of creating an entirely new runspace?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow how should i install Azure cli while running these scripts. Can you suggest. While doing this in windows powershell, It recognizes "az" command

Comment: If it's running on your local machine with azure CLI is installed, then it will work fine. If you're running it remotely (e.g. on a server) without CLI installed, then it will fail because it's trying to call the CLI that's not there. However, even if you're running locally, the CLI might not work inside this separetly created runspace (it might/might not - I've no idea whether, for instance, it's a personal environment variable that might NOT get loaded, or similar). So, let's go back to earlier - do you *need* this new runspace? Perhaps you can run this without it? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I am trying to read the PowerShell Script from c# console app so that I can use this as a web job in Azure. On trigger of a button the web job should run and ultimatly my script executes. I found the above code that was able to read the script. Do you want to recomend me any other way? I am trying to create Bot Service in Azure with this script,, but seems only "az" commands can create bot service. No other module i could able to find

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are clearing the Streams after the execution of the Command, so it flushes out the results.

```
// execute the script
var results = powershell.Invoke();
// Clears all the Streams 
powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
```

Try Clearing the Streams before the Invoke

```
// Clears all the Streams 
powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
// execute the script
var results = powershell.Invoke();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried but the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion above, I'd like to give a more complete answer, know that we know the scenario better.

For what you're trying to do, you're basically wanting to go from C# (in this case a web job in Azure) to connect the Azure back-end services to provision something. I'd suggest that, right now, there are too many technologies standing in your way. It's basically (right now):
Azure Webjob -> PowerShell -> Azure Cli ("az) -> Azure SDK -> Azure API (or Graph API)

Instead, I'd suggest you do one of the following:

1) considering you're in C#, you could **directly** call the Microsoft Graph API, skipping 3 technologies in the mix. For example, to create an Azure AD Application, you'd be calling the [Create application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint. Fortunately, you don't need to even call the endpoint directly, you can use the .net (i.e. C#) [SDK that Microsoft provides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk) for exactly this kind of operation.

2) Aside from that though, and just out of interest, why are you using a Web Job? I'd like to suggest you look into [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) instead - they're MUCH for lightweight (and possibly MUCH cheaper, depending on what you're trying to do)

3) Aside from the above, there are -totally- different ways to deploy and manage Azure artefacts (applications, bots, whatever). You should look into [Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/) as one option, or also something like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) on the "Infrastructure as Code" type of solution.

So some homework possibly for you, but hope that helps